Sci-Fi movie looking for name, dying lived, living died
I'm trying to remember the name of a sci-fi film most likely an early to mid 80's movie.
The plot is that people who were in the process of dying when the "device" was activated continue to live. And everybody else dies. The lead character of the movie is a scientist who committed suicide when the device (which he participated in the creation of) was activated. So he stayed alive.
A bizarre and memorable scene is when the group encounters various car wrecks and we see some fairly gruesome shots of living people who should be dead.
Does this sound familiar to anyone?

"The Quiet Earth" has a similar premise: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Quiet_Earth_(film)
" The three determine why they survived: at the instant of The Effect, they were all at the moment of death—Api was being drowned in a fight, Joanne was electrocuted by a faulty hairdryer, and Zac had overdosed on pills in a suicide attempt"

Welcome to the community. You may have more helpful information than you realize. If you know, please also describe the language, plot locale, names of actors, color or BW, etc. I hope you enjoy this place as much as I have.

See also http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/12530/identify-a-movie-where-people-who-died-at-a-certain-moment-lived/

I'm pretty sure that it is indeed The Quiet Earth. 
Those who died at the moment of the "Effect" survived, whilst everyone else disappeared. Zac Hobson was a scientist involved in Project Flashlight who commited suicide over guilt he felt at the  destructive potential of the device. He sees a dead car crash victim that had been thrown through the windscreen of a car, meaning the victim died at the moment of the "Effect", survived to again die from her injuries.
